# Strange vector initialization issue

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I recently debugged a strange C++ problem, in which a newly declared vector somehow had a size of 477218589. Here's the context:

```
struct Triangle {
    Point3 a,b,c;
    Triangle(Point3 x, Point3 y, Point3 z) : a(x), b(y), c(z) {}
    Vector3 flat_normal() { return (a-c)^(b-c); }
};

vector<Triangle> triangles;
```

Calling `triangles.size()` returns the value `477218589`.
I 'fixed' the problem by changing `struct Triangle` to `class Triangle`, but I'm wondering why there's any difference. Should I have done that `typedef struct Foo { ... } Foo;` magic? If so, why would that help?

If it matters, I'm using g++-4.1.

Comment: What you describe can be safely called "unlikely" for more reasons than one. Apparently, you are not posting the entire code. And no, changing `struct` to `class` will not fix the issue, if there ever was one, aside from causing the re-compilation of the translation unit(s).

Comment: You must turn off optimizations if you want to reliably watch variables during debugging. If it's the program itself which outputs the wrong value, please post a minimal compilable snippet that exhibits the behavior.

Comment: Well, I haven't been able to reproduce the bug elsewhere, so obviously it doesn't exist! :-P Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Point3 {};

struct Triangle {
    Point3 a,b,c;
    Triangle(Point3 x, Point3 y, Point3 z) : a(x), b(y), c(z) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Triangle> triangles;

    std::cout << triangles.size() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

prints `0` for me. If it also does for you, then the problem is in parts of the code not included in this snippet. If it prints anything else, something is fishy with your compiler/std lib/setup.

Comment: Well, here's an afterthought: You cannot use a type with a `std::vector`, unless it provides a default constructor. (My compiler doesn't detect this since the code snippet never attempts to populate the vector.) Since `Triangle` doesn't provide a default constructor, technically it might be invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Default constructor is only required if you call methods and want to use the defaults. `vec.resize(10);` - default constructor required or it won't compile otherwise, `vec.resize(10, Something(x, y));` - default constructor not required.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any difference between declaring `Triangle` as a struct or class - in C++, the difference between the two is that the default access specification of the members is public for struct and private for class, but that's it.

Is there anything more to `Triangle` that you didn't include?

Comment: I didn't think there was a difference, either! I've added the full contents of `Triangle`. `Point3` and `Vector3` are simple classes.